# How to sink kafka topic to oracle using kafka connect?

Tags: oracle, apache-kafka-connect

I have a kafka topic with data, following is config file I am using to sink data to oracle.

Sink.properties

```
name=ora_sink_task
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=person
connection.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521/XE
connection.user=kafka
connection.password=kafka
auto.create=true
insert.mode=upsert
pk.mode=record_value
pk.fields=id
```

I am getting following response in logs.

```
[2017-06-06 21:09:33,557] DEBUG Scavenging sessions at 1496504373557 (org.eclipse.jetty.server.session:347)
[2017-06-06 21:10:03,557] DEBUG Scavenging sessions at 1496504403557 (org.eclipse.jetty.server.session:347)
[2017-06-06 21:10:33,558] DEBUG Scavenging sessions at 1496504433558 (org.eclipse.jetty.server.session:347)
```

But no table is created in oracle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After changing topic name to PERSON in Kafka  and topics=PERSON in Sink.properties it worked.

Comment: This is because Kafka topic names are case-sensitive

Comment: Thanks @HansJespersen. But the problem here was with oracle, it needs Uppercase topic name to create table. While in mysql and postgres it was not the case.